# Redirect haproxy from url to another keeping this same path/uri

Tags: haproxy

I want to redirect as the below examples, keep the same path/uri but change the url.

https://test1.com/example1/example2 --> https://test2.com/example1/example2

I managed to do it for the url only by creating an acl acl_name base url and then do a redirect code 301 with an if conidtion.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, can you add the rule here ? It's easier to help you if we see what you did :)
If I understand well, by trying "https://test1.com/example1/example2" you get 301 "https://test2.com" but you want 301 "https://test2.com/example1/example2" ? Did you use this syntax ?
```
acl domain-test1-com hdr(host) -i test1.com
http-request redirect code 301 location http://test2.com%[capture.req.uri] if domain-test1-com
```